# How do I stop moderncv \homepage from automatically adding "http://" to my link?

Tags: pdftex

I am using `moderncv` to write a resume. The link I would like to put in `\homepage` is an https link. However `\homepage{https://foo.com}` generates `http://https://foo.com` in the pdf file. How do I stop `\homepage` from automatically adding that "http://" to my URL?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post a minimal working example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work, if you don't use any of the social-networking features:

```
\renewcommand*{\httplink}[2][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
    {\href{#2}{#2}}%
    {\href{#2}{#1}}}
```

This way it strips *all* of the `http://` from the code, which means that you have to put it back in yourself where needed.

Assuming all your links that you want to create in your CV are `https` links (even for social networking! I am not sure if this works with the social networking sites), you can alternatively define

```
\renewcommand*{\httplink}[2][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
    {\href{https://#2}{#2}}%
    {\href{https://#2}{#1}}}
```

which will make all hyperlinks formatted via `modercv` appear as `https` links.

---

A better solution would involve using the first option and then patching the social networking setting commands (if necessary) to use the non-`https` option.

Comment: It is a bit funny that while `moderncv` has abstracted the formatting command `\httplink`, it leaves the code displaying the homepage `\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}` littered through many, many Style files. Ideally if the above were abstracted into a macro `\showhomepage` then we can simply redefine `\showhomepage` to use the `https` version instead. As it stands to patch only the display of your homepage and nothing else will require a good deal more work.